# Google Fusion Table API Authentication Issue

Tags: rest, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to create a simple database with a Google Fusion Table, and make API calls from a browser to update / fetch data.  (The table is private, but set to exportable.)  But when I make a call from the browser, following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#browserURL using the syntax:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM {tableID}?key={APIkey}
```

and replacing {tableID} and {APIkey} with the values *directly from the browser*, I get the following 403 response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I've quadruple-checked my API key and syntax, and I even checked on the API console and it **does show multiple calls** being made for the FusionTables API.  What I need to do to ensure this authentication happens correctly, and that my data will actually be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Your second question mark should be an ampersand:

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM {tableID}&key={APIkey}

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I need to correct my post to show this.  This is the correct way, but I had actually already done this, and it still does not authenticate correctly - provides a 401 error response.  I will add this into my question after work.  Thanks for the help, @user1224571!